# Creating a map for relationship key besides using object property

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a Note class which has a relationship through Client class, and therefore has a property

```
public virtual Client Client {get; set;}
```

but how can I add a map to the client_id column, for example having

```
public virtual int? ClientId {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.

If you need to *get* the value of the FK, you can just do this:

```
var clientId = note.Client == null? (int?)null : note.Client.Id;
```

Accessing the id will *not* cause loading of the Client proxy.

If you need to *set* the value (and you have an id):

```
note.Client = session.Load<Client>(clientId);
```

Answer (score -1):

In the mapping class you would have:

```
Map(x => x.ClientId);
```